# PowerShell window when started from a batch file

Tags: powershell, command-line, batch-file

I have a batch file that starts a PowerShell script.

Batch file:

```
START Powershell -executionpolicy RemoteSigned -noexit -file "MyScript.ps1"
```

MyScript.ps1 :

```
Write-Output "Hello World!"
```

It works fine, with one exception. The appearance of the window is like the old cmd.exe (black background) and not the PowerShell (blue background).
How can I get the true PowerShell window, if I start it from a batch file?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all who have posted so far.  
I don't really care if the background is blue or black. I want to know why this is happening in the first place.  
If I do this:  
START notepad  
then the Notepad starts normally and there is no trace of cmd.exe around. Notepad looks exactly the same as if I started it from a shortcut.
Why is it different with PowerShell? Why is it different if I start it from a batch file vs from a shortcut?
And I kinda like being able to paste with a right-click in the new PowerShell.  
  
Thanks.

Comment: Also, by default, Command Prompt only retains 300 lines whereas PowerShell retains MANY more lines so if you're using something like `start powershell -noexit -executionpolicy unrestricted -file "PowerShell script.ps1"` then you need it to actually open in PowerShell, not Command Prompt, so you can see the full history of the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want a blue background, in your script add code to change the background color.

```
#save the original
$original=$host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor
$front=$host.ui.RawUI.ForegroundColor
$host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor="DarkBlue"
$host.ui.RawUI.ForegroundColor="White"
cls
#run your code
dir c:\scripts

#set it back
$host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor=$original
$host.ui.RawUI.ForegroundColor=$front
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a property of the shell link in the Start Menu which starts PowerShell, so you'd have to go through that:

```
start "" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk" ...
```

It's not pretty, it depends a little on where that resides (and might break on foreign language versions).

Comment: I tried it out on XP and no worky. I got a black shell. `start "" "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows PowerShell\Windows PowerShell.lnk"`. I had to use `explorer.exe` for it to honor the LNK properties.

Comment: Well, I'm on Windows 7 and it worked here. But that's what I was trying to tell you – it's a messy affair and likely to break down (especially in legacy OSes).

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke powershell so that it starts itself with the script

```powershell
Powershell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -noexit -File ""Full_Path_of_MyScript.ps1""'}"
```